# Create AMI of a given EC2 from cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

I have to create an AMI of a given EC2 istance from cloud formation, ad after create an ec2 from this AMI. How to do this? My principal problem is the first part

Comment: You can do it via Terraform apparently : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ami_from_instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is a function that can be called from as a CustomResource to create an AMI.

I haven't used it in a long time but it should still work.

Your CustomResource will need to pass in the `Region` and `Instance` (and `Tags` if you want those).

In order to create a new EC2 instance from this you would need to use the return value of `ImageId` and input that as the AMI to a AWS::EC2::Instance.

```
var Aws = require("aws-sdk");
var Response = require('cfn-response');

exports.handler = function (e, c) {

    console.log("REQUEST RECEIVED:\n" + JSON.stringify(e));

    // For Delete requests, immediately send a SUCCESS response.
    if (e.RequestType === "Delete") {
        Response.send(e, c, Response.SUCCESS);
        return;
    }

    console.log("Region=" + e.ResourceProperties.Region);
    console.log("Instance=" + e.ResourceProperties.Instance);

    var ec2 = new Aws.EC2({ region: e.ResourceProperties.Region });
    console.log("ec2=" + ec2);
    console.log("Tags=" + e.ResourceProperties.Tags);

    var params = {
        InstanceId: e.ResourceProperties.Instance,
        Name: e.ResourceProperties.AmiName
    };

    console.log("params=" + params);
    console.log("params.InstanceIds=" + params.InstanceIds);

    var responseStatus = "FAILED";

    ec2.createImage(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("createImage.err:" + err.toString(), err.stack.toString());
            Response.send(e, c, Response.FAILED);
        } // an error occurred
        else {
            console.log("createImage" + data);
            responseStatus = "SUCCESS";

            var responseData = {};
            responseData["ImageId"] = data.ImageId;

            var tagParams = {
                Resources: [data.ImageId],
                Tags: e.ResourceProperties.Tags
            }

            ec2.createTags(tagParams, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    data = { Error: "DescribeImages call failed" };
                    console.log(data.Error + ":\n", err);
                    Response.send(e, c, Response.FAILED);
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                    Response.send(e, c, Response.SUCCESS, responseData);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this.

AWS CloudFormation is designed to **deploy infrastructure in a repeatable manner**. It is used to create *new* infrastructure. It cannot be used to modify *existing* infrastructure.

You would need to create the AMI of the Amazon EC2 instance outside of CloudFormation. You can then use CloudFormation to launch a new Amazon EC2 instance using this AMI.

Comment: You could do that with custom resources.

Comment: Yes, but (shh!) I didn't want to raise that. The fact is, we can do _anything_ with a custom resource, but I would not consider this "clone an instance" requirement as an appropriate activity to do with CloudFormation (not to mention that it is reasonably complex to write a Custom Resource). Each to their own!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - SO encouraged me to write a comment as to why I downvoted this answer:  There is nothing about what OP is asking that is not a repeatable manner.  And just because something is complex, you shouldn't discourage others from attempting it.  If the OP has a need, it is not up to you to deem it inappropriate.

Comment: That's cool. @TimBassett I encourage you to add an answer that includes Custom Resources.